# Duplicate test method in test execution TestNg

Tags: java, integration-testing, testng

I want to execute same test method in two environments containing different environment parameters.

Simply i want to duplicate each test method in test execution with different system parametes.

Can i use implement this using IMethodInterceptor. Or using any extending facility in TestNg.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You can use TestNG [@Parameter](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters) ...

Java Code:

```
@Parameter({"parameterName"})
@Test
public void testMain(String parameterName) {}
```

TestNG XML Suite:

```
<suite name="Blah">
  <test name="1">
    <parameter name="parameterName" value="var1" />
    ...
  </test>

  <test name="2">
    <parameter name="parameterName" value="var2" />
    ...
  </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: Thanx for your answer , its perfect for situation where i have access to test. but here i cannot modify the test . I tried to modify the test in run time and add parameters to the test inside method interceptor but it didnt work. I just want to know whether there are any place i can make such change to test case and rerun the test method.

Comment: Are you able to share some code?  Maybe i'll be able to help you a bit more :)

Comment: Im working on sample code to post here. Thanx for your help. Basic architecture of my scenario is i use separate code  implemented based on testng listener and method interceptors to perform some start up and tear down functionalities and  do some modifications to test. My core is getting test packages as jars of as dependcy so i dont have control over test classes and testng.xml s

Answer (score 0):

It would depend a lot on how your tests are designed.
If your system parameters are being initialized in your tests currently and the system setup as well is in the tests, then anything you do before run, would be set back to what is in the test.

If you have those as global values for the tests, then you can use listeners to change the values based on params in the testng xml.  The params can be at test level and you can have sumtin like

```
<suite>
<test name="Sysconfig1">
<param name="sysparam1" value ="x"/>
<param name="sysparam2" value ="y"/>
<packages>
....
</test>
<test name="Sysconfig2">
<param name="sysparam1" value ="a"/>
<param name="sysparam2" value ="b"/>
<packages>
....
</test>
```

then implement the `onStart(ITestContext) of ITestListener and use sysproperty1 = context.getCurrentxmltest.gtparameter.get("sysparam1")`

Also the initialization of the environment can be done in these listeners implementations.
Just add the listener you implemented to your xml file under `<listeners>`

Hope it helps..